# Need help with Unbiased estimator 

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from a $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ distribution with probabilty function

$P(X=x) = (\theta^x)(1 - \theta)^{(1 - x)}$, $x=0,1$; $0<\theta<1$.

Is $\hat\theta(1 - \hat\theta)$ an unbiased estimator of $\theta(1 - \theta)$? Prove or disprove.

I tried $x=\theta(1-\theta)$, $\bar x=\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)$,

$E[\bar x)=x$

$E[\bar x(1-\bar x)]=E[\bar x]-E[\bar x-1)$

but I'm not sure what to do now or how to prove it. I have an exam tomorrow so any help is really appreciated! Hopefully this is the last stats question I'll have to ask!

Comment: could you use $tex$ to edit your post? it is difficult to read it.

Comment: relate it to the variance of $\hat \theta$

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Please do never use math mode for emphasizing words. *tex* looks better than $tex$...

Comment: I think $\TeX$ looks even better.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören how do I use tex? Or where do I learn to use it. People have to keep editing my questions

Comment: @Panda check this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören just used TeX in a question! Looks so much better! Hopefully people won't have to edit my questions too much anymore :)

Comment: ehehehe funny.. happy to hear.. It is okay if they edit as long as you use tex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$ $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$

Your notation is confusing: you use $x$ to refer to two different things, and you seem to use the lower-case $\bar x$ to refer to the sample mean after using capital letters to refer to random variables initially.

**Remember that the variance of a random variable is equal to the expected value of its square minus the square of its expected value.**  That enables us to find the expected value of its square if we know it variance and its expected value.

I surmise that by $\hat\theta$ you mean $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$.  That makes $\hat\theta$ an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

So $\E(\hat\theta) = \theta$ and
$$
\var(\hat\theta) = \var\left( \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{n^2}\var(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \frac{1}{n^2}(\var(X_1)+\cdots+\var(X_n))
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot n\var(X_1) = \frac 1 n \var(X_1) = \frac 1 n \theta(1-\theta).
$$

Now we want $\mathbb{E}(\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta))$:
$$
\mathbb{E}(\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)) = \mathbb{E}(\hat\theta) - \mathbb{E}(\hat\theta^2) = \theta - \Big( \var(\hat\theta) + \left(\E(\hat\theta)\right)^2 \Big) = \theta - \left( \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n} + \theta^2 \right)
$$
$$
= \frac{n\theta - \theta(1-\theta) - n\theta^2}{n} = \frac{n-1}{n}\theta(1-\theta).
$$

From this you can draw a conclusion about whether $\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta(1-\theta)$.

(By the way, $\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)$ is the maximum-likelihood estimator of $\theta(1-\theta)$.)

Comment: asymptotically unbiased estimator.